# Any a control panel for developers written in PHP for the CodeIgniter 2.0 framework like BackendPro?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed Codeigniter 2.1.0 and i'm looking for Admin Panel PHP opensource. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [backendpro](http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro). It provides require functionality to start with control panel like access control, groups etc. you can also try [CI-Backend](http://code.google.com/p/ci-backend/)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this into a CodeIgniter driven site a few times now

RevAxArts WhiteLabel Admin theme.

http://revaxarts-themes.com/?t=whitelabel

You can use it to rapidly build a clean backend admin framework with login dialogs, ajaxified forms, charts and dynamic widgets.

The only gotcha I've come across so far is that form posting through WhiteLabel is not so successful if you have used mod_rewrite to take the index.php? out of CodeIgniter's paths.